# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (n \alpha)} {n}$ converges for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, trigonometric-series

I want to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (n \alpha)} {n}$ converges for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Here is what I have:

> $\sin \alpha = \operatorname{Im}(\cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha)
> \\ \sin (x \alpha) = \operatorname{Im}(\cos (n \alpha) + i \sin (n \alpha) = \operatorname{Im}(\cos \alpha + i \sin (\alpha))^{n}\\
> \sum \sin(\alpha x) = \operatorname{Im} \sum (\cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha)^n \\
> \sum \sin(\alpha x) = \operatorname{Im} \frac{(\cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha)^{N+1} - (\cos \alpha + i sin \alpha)}{1 - (\cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha)} \leq \frac{4}{(1 - \cos \alpha)^2 + \sin^2 \alpha}
> $

I know that theorem that says that a series of nonnegative terms converges if and only if the partial sums form a bounded sequence. So using this theorem, is it safe to conclude that the series converges $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Your approach is basically correct, but just one little concern is that the case $\alpha=2k\pi$ needs a separate consideration.

Comment: @i707107 if $\alpha = 2k\pi $ wouldn't the sum converge to 0?

Comment: Yes, but the method in the question only works for $\alpha \neq 2k\pi$.

Comment: As a supplement to the comments by @i707107, the summation formula for geometric progression $\sum r^n=(1-r^{N+1})/(1-r)$ only works for $r\not=1$.

Comment: Are you sure about the "nonnegative" part, though?